# Sum rows in datagridview set label = the amount

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm a new student in development and I'm looking for C# code that can help me to make the label changes while sum of rows in datagridview

ex:
I'm using this code to calculate specific row in datagridview

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
   row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value = 
           (Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Qtty"].Index].Value) * 
           Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["PurchasePrice"].Index].Value));
}
```

What I want to do is: after I fill the `PurchasePrice` and `qtty` the amount should be calculated, after that when I press enter button the label should be = the same amount in `datagridview`.

thanks

edit:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)

        {
            row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value = (Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Qtty"].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["PurchasePrice"].Index].Value));
        }

        //datagridview column total in label
        decimal sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
        }

        lblSum.Text = sum.ToString();


        //vat
        decimal vat = (sum * 15 / 100);
        lblVat.Text = vat.ToString();

        //subtotal 
        decimal subtotal = (sum - vat);
        lblSubtotal.Text = subtotal.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: your question is not clear... what is the problem you are faced with? do you have a button? do you need help getting the selected row?

Comment: my problem needs to add a label on the form to showing sum of rows amount

Comment: you could calculate the sum in onclick like this: dataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().
                Sum(row => Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming the columns are all full and that part works correctly and what you want now is to have a label showing the sum of the amounts, you could do something like this:

```
    decimal SumAmounts = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
       decimal amount = (Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Qtty"].Index].Value) * 
                        (Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["PurchasePrice"].Index].Value));
       row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value = amount;
       SumAmounts += amount;
    }
    lblSum.Text = sumAmounts;
```

but you could also save the sum as a property and bind the label to it so that the label is always correct..

to do this you would need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your class and have a property that notifies when its changed:

```
private decimal sumAmount;
public decimal SumAmount { 
    get { return sumAmount; }
    set 
    { 
        sumAmount = value;
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SumAmount"));
        }
    }
}
```

then bind the label to the value in the ctor after InitilizeComponents:

```
lblSum.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this, "SumAmount");
```

and the code where you set the data would look like this:

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
       decimal amount = (Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Qtty"].Index].Value) * 
                        (Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["PurchasePrice"].Index].Value));
       row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value = amount;
       SumAmounts += amount;
    }
```

and now whenever you change SumAmounts - the label will automatically be updated.

you could read more about dataBinding here:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial

I hope this helps

Comment: tnks 4yr help
I used this code which gives me what I want
Now,I need to add2labels for (subtotal and vat)
so,the code should be what?
dataGridView1_CellEndEdit()
{
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value = (Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Qtty"].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["PurchasePrice"].Index].Value));}
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++){sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);}
lblSum.Text = sum.ToString();

Comment: I noticed you didnt use the binding option - so assuming they are both calculated from the sum,  you could do (change the percentage to whatever it is there):           const int VAT_PERCENTAGE = 17;
            decimal vat = (SumAmount * VAT_PERCENTAGE / 100);
            lblVat.Text = vat.ToString(); 
            lblSubtotal.Text = (sum + vat).ToString();

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly - the user enters data in the "Qtty" and "PurchasePrice" columns, the "Amount" column is to display the "Qtty" * "PurchasePrice".
If that's the case then use the [CellEndEdit event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit?view=netframework-4.5) and check if both columns have data in the correct format, something like this:

```
const double VAT_PERCENT = 15; // Added for VAT calculation
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var isQty = int.TryParse(
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Qtty"].Value?.ToString().Trim(),
        out int qty);

    var isPrice = int.TryParse(
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["PurchasePrice"].Value?.ToString().Trim(),
        out int price);
    
    // Added SubTotal and VAT calculations    
    if (isQty && isPrice)
    {
        double percent = VAT_PERCENT / 100;
        double subtotal = qty * price / (1 + percent);
        double vat = qty * price - subtotal;
        int amount = qty * price;
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Amount"].Value = amount;
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["SubTotal"].Value = subtotal;
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["VAT"].Value = vat;
    }
}
```

Comment: tnks 4yr help
I used this code which gives me what I want
Now,I need to add2labels for (subtotal and vat)
so,the code should be what?
dataGridView1_CellEndEdit()
{
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value = (Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Qtty"].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["PurchasePrice"].Index].Value));}
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++){sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);}
lblSum.Text = sum.ToString();

Comment: ex:
Qtty = 2 and PurchasePrice = 5
so, lbl of Sub total = 8.70
lbl of VAT = 1.30
lbl of Total/Sum = 10

so, how the code should be?

Comment: @user14305004 the labels need to show this information for entire table or just each row?

Comment: @audzzy
How to calculate VAT like the following example
purchase price 100 with vat 15%
so, sub total should be = 86.96
vat = 13.04
total = 100
so in this case the vat is included in the purchase price

Comment: @user14305004 please see answer edit with SubTotal and VAT added.

Comment: my issue now in the calculation of vat and sub total is incorrect
it's give me sub total is 85 and vat is 15 when the amount is 100
while the correct result should be sub total is 86.96 and vat 13.04 with same amount
ao, any help..

Comment: @user14305004 please edit the question with details and code example of these issues.

Comment: @user14305004 the VAT calculation is incorrect and the subtotal will also be incorrect, please see my answer for the correct calculations - if VAT is 15 percent then to calculate subtotal from 100 will be  --> 100 / (1 + (15 / 100)) = 100 / 1.15 = 86.96

Comment: like this
decimal sum = 0;
           for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {sum += Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);}
            lblSum.Text = sum.ToString();
            //vat
            decimal vat = (sum * 15 / 100);
            lblVat.Text = vat.ToString();
            //100 / (1 + (15 / 100))
            //subtotal 
            decimal subtotal = (sum - vat );
            lblSubtotal.Text = subtotal.ToString();

Comment: it was already in the code inside of the if statement, but here it is: 
`const double VAT_PERCENT = 15;`
`double percent = VAT_PERCENT / 100;`
`double subtotal = qty * price / (1 + percent);`
`double vat = qty * price - subtotal;`

Comment: sorry it's giving me an error with under qty and price
should I do qty and price like a new variable or no?
because I have another Qtty and PurchasePrice in datagridview

Comment: yes, those can be variables of the `CellEndEdit` event, and then assuming the grid has a column for VAT and SubTotal those values can be assigned to them just like the `Amount` column.
Please also specify what error / exception it's showing.

Comment: I have a combobox column inside datagridview called items name and it's read items from db, I need to make 2nd column in datagridview to showing ID while items is selected?
my code for first items name column is :
com.Connection = con;
con.Open();
com.CommandText = "select * from Goods";
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
DataTable dt7 = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da7 = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
da7.Fill(dt7);
ComboColumn.DataSource = dt7;
ComboColumn.DisplayMember = "Name";

con.Close();

Comment: @user14305004 the comments here and the question was already re-iterated multiple times with unrelated questions to the original question posted, if this answer solved the original question then please mark it as accepted.

If you have a new question or a different issue then please open a new question.

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Answer (score 0):

private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)

```
        {
            row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value = (Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Qtty"].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["PurchasePrice"].Index].Value));
        }

        //datagridview column total in label
        decimal sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
        }

        lblSum.Text = sum.ToString();

        const double VAT_PERCENT = 15;
        double percent = VAT_PERCENT / 100;
        double subtotal = Qtty * [price error here] / (1 + percent);
        double vat = Qtty * [price error here] - subtotal;
}
```